# Can't find QT5 modules on Mac using cmake for Musescore

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cmake

Trying to compile Musescore (Master branch as of 7/19/2018) with cmake but cmake can't seem to find the QT modules

Installed QT5 using online installer

```
qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.11.1 in /Users/me/Qt/5.11.1/clang_64/lib
```

Added this to Makefile as suggested from other answers but still doesn't work

```
  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/Users/me/Qt/5.11.1/clang_64/lib/cmake"


  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/Users/me/Qt/5.11.1/clang_64/lib" \

  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/Users/me/Qt/5.11.1/clang_64" \
```

Here's the error when I do `make -f Makefile.osx release`

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    FindQt5


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:64 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    UsePkgConfig1


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:65 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    FindPulseAudio


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:66 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    GetCompilerVersion


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:67 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    CreatePrecompiledHeader


MuseScore SoundFont is up to date.
-- ALSA support disabled
-- PulseAudio support disabled
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:333 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    FindLame


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:379 (PKGCONFIG1):
  Unknown CMake command "PKGCONFIG1".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/me/MuseScore/build.release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
xcodebuild: error: 'mscore.xcodeproj' does not exist.
xcodebuild: error: 'mscore.xcodeproj' does not exist.
make: *** [release] Error 66
```

I also tried doing the brew qt way but that did not work either, got the same error (can't find the modules)

Comment: These files are in the `build/` directory of the project. Don't you have this directory cleared? (E.g. for build the project there).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yea I deleted the `build/` folder using `make -f Makefile.osx clean` and also tried manually deleting it and tried compiling again but still got the same error

Comment: Well, you **should not** delete `build/` directory after checkouting the project. Again, this directory contains files, marked as missed in your error log. (I agree, that having non-generated files under `build/` directory isn't a wise idea, but the project developers decided to do so.)